# Make vimdiff show entire file

Tags: vimdiff

How can you have vimdiff show the entire contents of the files being differenced?  I'd like the color highlights of the differences, but would still like to see the entire files, i.e. the parts that are identical as well.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`vimdiff` sets `foldmethod diff` so all unchanged lines are folded. From inside `vimdiff` you can open all folds by pressing `zR`.

If you would like to always show the full context you could increase the number of unfolded  context lines shown to some large number. In your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if &diff                             " only for diff mode/vimdiff
  set diffopt=filler,context:1000000 " filler is default and inserts empty lines for sync
endif
```

Comment: Yes, `zR` is the way to go. Note: `za` will recreate the folds.

Comment: @sleske `za` doesn't close but `zM` does, as evident from @Thomas 's answer.

Comment: @MycrofD: Yes. To be precise: `za` will close a single fold (the one under the cursor); `zM` will close all folds. Both can be useful.

Comment: Is there any option to increase unfolded context lines in the  vimdiff command itself. This will be useful while running from shell script file.

Comment: Yes, there is see, http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'diffopt', e.g., to view with 42 lines of context one could set `set diffopt+=context:42`.

Answer (score 12):

This answer to the question on stackoverflow is worth checking.

[Vimdiff: What are the most frequently used commands/shortcuts that could get a newbie started?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292629/311288)

in a nutshell:
`zo` and `zc` to respectively open and close a section
`zM` and `zR` to respectively expand and fold all the sections

Answer (score 7):

Placing the cursor on the line you want to expand and hitting the space bar works for me!

It seems like I've had to use the arrow keys sometimes too.